# Zend - Catchable fatal error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am getting error while running following code

```
$value_sql = "SELECT test_fielf FROM `tbl_test` where `site_id`='".$sid."'";
$register_value = $db->fetchRow($value_sql);
echo $register_value;die();
```

The error : `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Comment: I think $sid is an object, just var_dump it.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use `echo` for printing objects

```
$value_sql = "SELECT test_fielf FROM `tbl_test` where `site_id`='".$sid."'";
$register_value = $db->fetchRow($value_sql);
print_r( $register_value);
die();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code you posted is as-is, you're missing a closing double-quote on the first line.

```
$value_sql = "SELECT test_fielf FROM `tbl_test` where `site_id`='".$sid."'";
$register_value = $db->fetchRow($get_register_value_sql);
echo $register_value;die();
```

The error you're experiencing is due to `$register_value = $db->fetchRow($get_register_value_sql);` returning an object, not a string.  If you wish to treat is as a string, then you can cast is as a string using:

```
$register_value = (string) $db->fetchRow($get_register_value_sql);
```

Comment: @MarkMartin What is $sid? Is it not a string?

Comment: @moonwave99 Yes it would have caused the error reported by OP because they are **double**-quotes which means that the variables inside the string (`$db`) are being interpolated (evaluated and concatenated).

Comment: @MihaiStancu I say that a missing quote would have thrown an uncatchable syntax error like "unexpected something" ^^

Comment: @RobB don't cast an object to string, if the object does not implement `__toString()` method then it will have no effect - the same error will occuri. In stead you have to `var_dump` or `print_r` the object.

Comment: @moonwave99 you're right a syntax error would have been outputted before any other errors. It means it was just the `echo $Object;` that was triggering this error.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$value_sql = "SELECT test_fielf FROM `tbl_test` where `site_id`='" . $sid . "'";
$register_value = $value_sql -> fetchRow(DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);
print_r($register_value);
die();
```